# How to read form field in Microsoft Powerapps

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I have a form in Microsoft Powerapps (Canvas app). When I submit the form, I want to run a Power Automate flow that sends email to the user with the form data.

Email and form submission is working fine but we cannot read data from *form data fields*.

On button click, we are running:

```
CreatePropertyFlow.Run("some@email", "some_subject", Concatenate(DataCardValue14.Text, " in ", DataCardValue17.Text));
```

[image]

The email body is supposed to have for example:

```
Veritas in Pune
```

But we are receiving only:

```
in
```

Which means it is not able to read values from :

DataCardValue14.Text

&

DataCardValue17.Text

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried it on my end abd able to get the values from form fields. Can you confirm if you able to access form fields value outside Run method?

Comment: Your formula syntax looks fine and it should get the values properly. Can you check if you have used this data correctly in power automate?